# How to install CUDA Profiling Tools Interface on windows 10

Tags: tensorflow, memory-management, cuda

My goal is figure out the memory usage of neural network models build in tensorflow. Therefore, I figured out that I have to install the following library: CUDA Profiling Tools Interface on my windows 10 machine. Hence, this could happen simply through: `sudo apt-get install libcupti-dev` on linux. What is the equivalence of this command on windows 10? Please note that I have CUDA v9.0 on my machine with tensorflow 1.8.

I tried the following code:

```
import os
import tempfile

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.layers import fully_connected as fc
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
from tensorflow.python.client import timeline

batch_size = 100

inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, 784])
targets = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, 10])

with tf.variable_scope("layer_1"):
    fc_1_out = fc(inputs, num_outputs=500, activation_fn=tf.nn.sigmoid)
with tf.variable_scope("layer_2"):
    fc_2_out = fc(fc_1_out, num_outputs=784, activation_fn=tf.nn.sigmoid)
with tf.variable_scope("layer_3"):
    logits = fc(fc_2_out, num_outputs=10)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=targets))
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mnist_save_dir = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'MNIST_data')
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(mnist_save_dir, one_hot=True)

    config = tf.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
        run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
        for i in range(3):
            batch_input, batch_target = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            feed_dict = {inputs: batch_input,
                         targets: batch_target}

            sess.run(train_op,
                     feed_dict=feed_dict,
                     options=options,
                     run_metadata=run_metadata)

            fetched_timeline = timeline.Timeline(run_metadata.step_stats)
            chrome_trace = fetched_timeline.generate_chrome_trace_format()
            with open('timeline_02_step_%d.json' % i, 'w') as f:
                f.write(chrome_trace)
```

and I got the following error:

```
2019-01-03 13:49:50.347482: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:142] Couldn't open CUDA library cupti64_90.dll
2019-01-03 13:49:50.347629: F T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow/stream_executor/lib/statusor.h:212] Non-OK-status: status_ status: Failed precondition: could not dlopen DSO: cupti64_90.dll; dlerror: cupti64_90.dll not found

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: How about reading some documentation? https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#installing-cuda-development-tools

Comment: I have downloaded the toolkit a long time ago already. But I want to only download for now the CUDA Profiling Tools Interface, and not the whole toolkit as it won't be compatible with tensorflow

Comment: Download again or re-run the installer for the CUDA version you have and follow the instructions I linked to

Comment: @talonmies, I was looking into the CUDA folder on my machine, and found that cupti is already download into the following folder: `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\extras\CUPTI` This folder contains the `include`, `libwin32`, `libx64`, `sample` and `Readme`... So I am not sure what should I do next in order to avoid reinstalling CUDA

Comment: Nothing, it is already installed. From a CUDA perspective, you are done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is solved according to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6235 @menggangmark as:

"The file cupti64_90.dll lies in C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\extras\CUPTI\libx64. I just fixed the problem by copying the dll into C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin, and the file cupti.lib in the same location into C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\lib\x64. And it works!"

Comment: You could just as easily have adding the CUPTI install path into the DLL search order and it would work. Also please remember to come back and accept you answer so this falls off the unanswered list